# Does Salesforce Shield Field Audit trail allow field history tracking on detail objects in master details

Tags: master-detail, field-history, shield

Need to know about field audit trail, Salesforce shield.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user has shown no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Salesforce Shield allows you to track field history tracking of detail objects. You can track 60 fields.

For more information, refer my blog.
[Platform Encryption - Things to know before activating Platform Shield](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2018/02/platform-encryption-what-to-know-before.html)

Also refer [Secure Your Apps with Salesforce Shield](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/shield) trail

Comment: Thanks Shantanu. I explorede documentation. However it didn't mention anything particular.